# How to answer "Are you permanent employee?" when applying for mortgage as an apprentice

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, employment

I've been looking into getting a mortgage with my partner recently. We had a conversation with the bank yesterday asking all the standard questions (How much do you earn?, Monthly outgoing, etc..). They also asked how long we had been employed for by our current company and if we were both on permanent contracts. My partner could answer this with a simple yes. I was unsure how to answer as I am actually an apprentice in the UK.

My employment contract says "You are employed for a fixed-term until 2023". It also talks about how much I would get paid for a full role from 2023, but it does not say "You will be employed with a full role" or anything similar.

I've tried to look into this but the only thing I could really find is this [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/fixed-term-contracts) website saying an apprenticeship is not a fixed term contract.

Do I need to tell the bank that I am an apprentice or not? They haven't asked for our job titles at all.

Comment: Depending on the field, the bank will probably be fine with the idea that you have a 4 year contract and will have an apprenticeship at the end of it. When speaking to your mortgage advisor be as honest as possible; this will be only one of many factors considered in your application.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon could you turn that into an answer (you're also welcome to edit mine)?

Answer (score 4):

Given that your employment contract explicitly says it's "fixed-term", I don't think you can say it's permanent.

The government site about fixed-term contracts is talking about specific rights that employees on fixed-term contracts get. In that context, I think excluding apprenticeships is just to make it clear that those specific rights don't apply to apprentices. It doesn't change the natural meaning of the idea of "fixed-term" in other contexts.